# How to execute shellScript using oozie

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, sqoop

I have following sqoop job which i written in **sqoopJob.sh**

-----------myscript.sh------------------

```
TARGET_DIR=date+"%Y_%m_%d"

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb --username root --password root --table Customer --m 1 --target-dir   /temp/$TARGET_DIR
```

Which I want to execute using oozie.

It gives me following error

> Cannot run program "CustomerImportScript.sh" (in directory "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/appcache/application_1449233755312_0070/container_e11_1449233755312_0070_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: could you cleanup and indent correctly your question? it even seem that your sqoop call is commented in your script...

Comment: could you please share the Details Log of the Workflow from JobHistory, that will help more to find the reason, check the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416015/running-shell-script-with-oozie) for reference

Answer (score 1):

Check what is the OS user under which oozie runs, possibly that user/group does not have permissions to execute the script.

Try invoking the command in the command line and post the result.

Also check the permissions of the entire directory tree.